# HTMX, Flask, how to trigger an event for outof scope tag

Tags: python, flask, htmx

I have a page that i am attempting to update to different elements on.

```
        <div class="main-table-container" id="tableMain">
            <div id="inventoryTable" class="inventory-table">
                <div hx-get="{{url_for('auth.inventory_table')}}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="load once"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-column">
                <div id="orderTable" class="order-table">
                    <div hx-get="{{url_for('auth.stock_orders')}}" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="load once"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The tables call their respective routes and load correctly, however when calling the method within the stock_orders table the stock orders table is updated but i am trying to update the inventory table along side this

```
<table class="table-container">
    <tr class="table-header">
        <th class="table-cell">Orders</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-header">
        <th class="table-cell">Status</th>
    </tr>
    {% for order in orders %}
    <tr class="table-row">
        <td class="confirm-order-btn" hx-post="{{url_for('auth.confirm_order', id=order.id)}}" hx-target="#orderTable">
            Confirm delivery
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

orders_table partial:

```
    {% for order in orders %}
    <tr class="table-row" id="stock_orders_li">
        <td hidden>{{ order.id }}</td>
        <td class="table-cell">{{ order.supplier }}</td>
        <td class="table-cell">{{ order.name }}</td>
        <td class="table-cell">{{ order.description }}</td>
        <td class="table-cell">{{ order.quantity }}</td>
        <td class="table-cell">{{ order.delivery_date }}</td>
        <td class="table-cell">{{ order.status }}</td>
        <td class="confirm-order-btn" hx-post="{{url_for('auth.confirm_order', id=order.id)}}" hx-target="#orderTable"
            id="confirm-order-btn">
            Confirm delivery </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

How can i go about doing this?

Comment: That can be achieved by using `hx-swap-oob` attribute. Take a look at [how](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/)

Comment: Im struggling to understand how it is done, which tag gets """hx-swap-oob"""?

Comment: Can you include the partial for orders_table.

Comment: The order table like such?

Comment: When you confirm an order, is that the content that's swapped into the **#orderTable**?

Comment: Yes, this partial is swapped into the **#orderTable**